# send metadata and content as base64 encoded for pdf and xlsx documents

Tags: wso2-esb

My requirement is to send metadata and content of pdf and xlsx files as base64 encoded to backend system.

Can I acheive it using WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate your requirement more?  eg: sample request etc. Let us know your complete use case .Also how do you send the pdf content to ESB is it as HTTP request or using reading as file system.